# Postfix: after address rewriting (using aliases LDAP) rewrite 'To' header

Tags: email, postfix, aliases

we want to implement in our LDAP a sort of 'address book' and use Postfix to modify outgoing e-mails to use these aliases.

The idea is that when a user writes to customer1@ourdomain.tld, the LDAP query retrieves e-mails (external or internal) and send the e-mail to all of them.

This works well, implemented with

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf
```

My problem is that when users receive the e-mail sent to this alias, they see the alias used not their own address (or all addresses), which we would prefer.

I have read http://postfix.cs.utah.edu/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html and tried to do it with canonical or header_checks but can't find the correct solution.

Do anyone knows how to implement this?